# SQL iteration-Insertion plus renaming

Tags: optimization, performance, sql, sql-server

**Base Info**

- Two tables: tData, tData2
- Exactly the same columns
- About 200,000 records
- SQL Server 2008 R2

**Logic**

At first sight we need to insert tData rows into tData2. What else?

We need a renamed version of a column inside another (tData2)
with the condition checking it won't be an existing item when it's renamed.
Here's the code:

```
INSERT INTO [tData2]
(
    [Key],
    Info1,
    Info2
)
SELECT 
    REPLACE([Key],'_',' '),
    Info1,
    Info2
FROM
    [tData]
WHERE
    (REPLACE([Key],'_',' ') = [Key]) OR
    (REPLACE([Key],'_',' ') NOT IN (SELECT [Key] FROM [tData]))
```

The problem is it's really slow for me on a top-notch 64 bit system. It has taken more than an hour so far and it's still executing.

How to speed it up? Any alternatives? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a DBA/DBMS guru, so just some ideas:

- Turn off indexes on `tData2` during the migration.
- Do it in smaller chunks for smaller transaction log. ([Batch commit on large INSERT operation in native SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1602244/843804), [How to implement LIMIT with Microsoft SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/603724/843804))
- Make sure that `[tData].[Key]` has an index.
- I'd consider replacing the subselect with a join if it's possible at all.

Comment: Anyway this is a valuable comment, I liked it, Could you please give an example on the last part you mentioned ?

Comment: @Sypress: I'm sorry, I've tried to rewrite the query but I gave it up after a few tries. I haven't used so complex SQL queries recently. Please let me know how went the  migration and what worked or not.

Comment: no problem friend, thanks again, your suggestions could be useful to me.